# Frameworks to store data client side

Tags: html, browser, client-side, local-storage

Are there any frameworks or API to store data client side conveniently, by transferring from database, during user's session ? I'm looking for any framework so that I dont have to, perhaps,  care about whether or not the browser support `LocalStorage` or other storage technologies & I can seamlessly store data!?

For my personal use case, I need to be able to pass an unfiltered list of recommended items for user & remove the ones he has added to his lists. I want to store the user's lists client side and then filter the unadded items.

Comment: There might be some caching mechanisms try to utilize them.

Comment: @user what is wrong with using `localStorage` because it is supported by all major browsers: [click here](http://w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: @AidanMueller: because only the most recent versions of browsers support HTML 5 storage: FireFox 3, Safari 4, and IE 8;

Comment: and what's wrong with cookies? you could combine them both. so if one can't be used, use the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [YUI's StorageUtility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/). The YUI StorageUtility is a nice abstraction

> > The Storage Utility provides a mechanism for storing significant amounts of textual data, client-side, whether or not your browsers
> >     supports the proposed HTML 5 Storage specification.
> >
> > Each instance of the Storage Utility leverages one of three storage
> >     engines in order to store data:
> >
> > **HTML 5**: If the client browser supports HTML 5, then this engine will
> >     wrap the browser's native storage capability (document.localStorage
> >     and document.sessionStorage).
> >         **Google Gears**: Google Gears is a browser
> >     extension that users can install on their machine. One of its features
> >     is a SQLite database; the Storage Utility uses this database for
> >     client-side storage when using the Gears engine.
> >       **SWF**: YUI provides a
> >     SWFStore Utility that normalizes access to the Flash Shared Object.
> >     This is the Storage Utility's fallback engine, which will work on most
> >     browsers due to the significant penetration of the Adobe Flash plugin.

Answer (score 3):

[Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) abstracts away the various storage mechanisms available via a series of [adapters](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/adapters/). It can utilize localStorage, indexedDB, web SQL, and more.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) or [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 0):

Client side storage libraries- Automatically choose storage based on browser

http://amplifyjs.com/ - is a good option

http://pablotron.org/software/persist-js/

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jstore/

Answer (score 0):

you can check [Lungo](http://www.lungojs.com/) is a Mobile HTML5 Framework, you can find your [Data API](http://www.lungojs.com/api/#doc-data) really interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a ton of them at [microjs.com](http://microjs.com/#storage)

For example, [Artemia](https://github.com/k33g/artemia/)